# in mysql we have SOUNDEX() or we can use SOUNDS LIKE for related / wrong spells or words matching so is their any thing like in BIGQUERY

Tags: mysql, sql, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, spell-checking

in **mysql** we have

> SOUNDEX()

and

> SOUNDS LIKE

for related / wrong spellings or words matching in query

Is there anything like that or similar in BigQuery? Can BigQuery be used for such queries?

Answer (score 4):

Using [BigQuery User-Defined Functions (UDF)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) in JavaScript you can simply implement SOUNDEX function yourself.

Here is SQL statement for BigQuery that calculate SOUNDEX:

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION SOUNDEX(name STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  if (name == null) return null;
  let s = [];
  let si = 1;
  let c;
  //              ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
  let mappings = "01230120022455012623010202";
  s[0] = name[0].toUpperCase();
  for(let i = 1, l = name.length; i < l; i++) {
    c = (name[i].toUpperCase()).charCodeAt(0) - 65;
    if(c < 0 || c > 25) { continue; }
    if(mappings[c] == '0') { continue; }
    if(mappings[c] != s[si-1]) {
      s[si] = mappings[c];
      si++;
    }
    if(si > 3) { break; }
  }
  if(si <= 3) {
    while(si <= 3) {
      s[si] = '0';
      si++;
    }
  }
  return s.join("");
""";

SELECT SOUNDEX("John Doe"), SOUNDEX("Jon Do")
```

Credit: I took the original JavaScript code from [Chris Webb blog](http://www.code-in-javascript.com/author/cw77gh/) post [here](http://www.code-in-javascript.com/the-soundex-algorithm-in-javascript/) and slightly change the coding syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked in the "Google BigQuery Analytics" book, and no, BigQuery does not have anything like "SOUNDEX()" (at least at the time of publishing).

You might want to check [cloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs), which is a mysql server hosted on the cloud. I know there are some functions from mysql you can't use in the cloudSQL, but it would be worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question was asked years ago, but for those who wander here as I did looking for answers, here you go.

BigQuery does now have SOUNDEX()

[Here is the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#soundex)